# H2 database doesn't respect constraint rule

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, junit, spring-boot, h2

I've got in my `spring-boot` project 2 databases - MS SQL Server for application itself and `H2` for integration tests. The `schema.sql` file for `H2` is identical with the create script for the `SQL Server` database and it contains a constraint which says, that solely one of two attributes must be set up. My unit test works fine with `SQL Server`, but doesn't behave as expected with `H2`. The `MODE=MSSQLServer` is set. This test should fail, nevertheless it finishes with success.

```
@Test
public void testDatabaseConstraints() {

    ConversationThread corruptedConversationThread = new ConversationThread();
    corruptedConversationThread.setConversationThreadId(new ConversationThreadId("corruptedConversationThread"));
    corruptedConversationThread.setThreadCategory(threadCategory);

    // only family or familyMember can be set, not both at the same time
    corruptedConversationThread.setFamily(family);
    corruptedConversationThread.setFamilyMember(familyMember);

    conversationThreadRepository.save(corruptedConversationThread);
}
```

The constraint in the sql script is:

```
CREATE
TABLE conversationthread
(
  id                                   VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
  family_number                         INTEGER ,
  familyMember_number                       INTEGER ,
  thread_category_id                VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT conversationThread_PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (id)
    WITH
    (
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON
    )
    ON "default"
)
ON "default"
GO
ALTER TABLE conversationthread
  ADD CONSTRAINT check_only_one_column_is_null
CHECK (
  (CASE WHEN family_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   + CASE WHEN familyMember_number IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  = 1
)
GO
```

Does anybody have any idea, how to force `H2` database to make this constraint to work, which would result in failing of the test, I posted?

Comment: Another good example what it's a bad idea to use a different DBMS for testing and production. The create table statement will not run at all in H2 (and neither will the `GO` keyword). The check constraint itself should work though (if you can create the table)

Comment: Well..probably it's not an ideal way, but nor would be to have an extra database just for quick integration tests... All other tests, that are expected to fail have the same problem. Only those, who should end positively (like save, delete, etc.) work fine..

Comment: In the documentation http://www.h2database.com/h2.pdf at page 45 you can see which features the MSSQL compatibility mode supports. The special constraint syntax is not there, so it seems it's not supported

Comment: Oh! A good point! Thanks for sharing this document!